# dismisscontroller delegate method not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, dismissviewcontroller

I have 2 `viewcontroller`s, first VC contains backButton.

**firstVC.h**

```
@protocol DVDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)DVViewControllerDismissed:(NSString *)stringForFirst;
@end
```

and also contains delegate property

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<DVDelegate> myDelegat;
```

**firstVC.m**

backButton code for firstVC

```
- (IBAction)backButton_Click:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"EEEEEE:%@",_DFCJ);
    if([_DFCJ isEqual:@"DL"]){
        NSLog(@"159");
        if([self.myDelegat respondsToSelector:@selector(DVViewControllerDismissed:)])
        {
            [self.myDelegat DVViewControllerDismissed:_DFCJ];//this method not call 
            NSLog(@"aPP");
        }
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"5555");
    }
}
```

**SecondVC.m**

```
@interface DiamondListVC ()<DVDelegate>
```

receive below method

```
-(void)DVViewControllerDismissed:(NSString *)stringForFirst;{
    NSLog(@"AASASS");
   [self performSelector:@selector(callService) withObject:self afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

**Result log**

```
2018-04-21 09:33:39.382 search[907:16573] EEEEEE:DL
2018-04-21 09:33:39.382 search[907:16573] 159
2018-04-21 09:33:39.383 search[907:16573] 5555
```

but firstVC won't dismiss, please see my code and give me a suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your delegate should be `weak` instead of `assign`.

Comment: @trungduc: wait i try.not working bro.

Comment: I think it happens because of a problem with your delegate. Maybe it's nil. Can you show where did you set delegate?

Comment: as you see my code. set in firstVC.

Comment: No, I don't see it. I need something like `self.myDelegat = secondVC`

Comment: ok let me try..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169484/discussion-between-rb1509-and-trungduc).

Comment: Show the code where you assign your instance if secondVc as the delegate of the first vc

Comment: @Paulw11 like trungduc comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `firstVC` can't be dismissed because `firstVC` is pushed from `secondVC`, not presented.

To pass data from `firstVc` to `secondVc`, you don't need to use delegate. You can get `secondVC` from `firstVC` by using `self.navigationController.viewControllers`.

**FirstVC.m**

```
- (IBAction)backButton_Click:(id)sender {
  NSLog(@"EEEEEE:%@",_DFCJ);
  if([_DFCJ isEqual:@"DL"]){
    NSLog(@"159");

    // Get |SecondVC| by using |self.navigationController.viewControllers|
    NSArray* viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers]; 
    SecondVC *previousViewController = viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 2]; 
    [previousViewController DVViewControllerDismissed:_DFCJ];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"5555");
  }
}
```

**SecondVC.h**

```
@interface DiamondListVC : YourClass

-(void)DVViewControllerDismissed:(NSString *)stringForFirst;

@end
```

Comment: this line fire no visible interface [(SecondVC*)self.presentingViewController DVViewControllerDismissed:_DFCJ];

Comment: What do you mean `fire no visible interface`?

Comment: dispaly no visible intrface

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: If `firstVC` is presented from `secondVC`, I'm sure that when you call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` it will be dismissed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169487/discussion-between-rb1509-and-trungduc).